# WARNING:Xst:1290 and WARNING:Xst:528

Tags: vhdl

Please help regarding the warning and error of my program

> WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <bjn9> is unconnected in block <sequencedetector>.
>      It will be removed from the design.
>   WARNING:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <sequencedetector> on signal  not replaced by logic
>   Sources are: sg16_Mxor_q_Result:Result, sg15_Mxor_r_Result:Result

for following program

```
bjn9: bjn
    port map (s12,s14,o,g9,g10,s15);
```

Suggest the steps for correction in VHDL code

Comment: There isn't enough information present. This isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nor enough to guess. [Xst:528](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/14264.html) refers to multiple drivers on the same net.

Comment: And neither of those messages are errors. It may well be that they are expected and can safely be ignored. Only you can tell that, in the context of the overall design.

Answer (score 1):

#### Unconnected block warning

Possible solutions to remove the warning:

1. Remove the `bjn9` instance.
2. Connect any of the outputs of `bjn9` to something that uses them.

#### Multi-source warning

Possible solutions to remove the warning:

1. Remove all but one of the multiple sources.
2. Add logic to combine the sources to a single signal.

Comment: [WARNING XST:1290](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/WARNING-Xst-1290-Hierarchical-block-is-unconnected-in-block-lt/td-p/126600) "The most common reasons for large sections of a design to suddenly get ripped out are  missing clocks or constantly asserted resets. Either of these will cause all the downstream  logic to get replaced with constants, and hence ripped out of the design."